# How to connect to a server running on my pc using my app on my android device

Tags: android

I have written a server-side program using JAVA that is running on my PC using my PC as the server, and using a client program I had written using Java I was able to connect to the server program using "localhost" as the ip name and using the port I had specified in my server-socket object in my server-side program.

Now I have transformed my client program into an android app and I'm running it on my phone, how can I connect to the server program that is running on my PC? DO I need to change the socket defined in my android app or does it work the same way as the desktop app?

Comment: Is the server side code hosted on Glassfish or Tomcat ?

Comment: @ShishirShetty No It's a simple program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the desktop version works you can use it in Android also . But some notes to keep in mind

- Add permission in manifest
  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
- Do your Network operations in a `background thread` using `AsyncTask`

Comment: The background thread is the most important issue in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following things,

1. Make sure both of the phone and desktop are connected to the same network.
2. Use your desktop's local IP address instead of using "localhost".
3. Make sure you have set proper permission to access the desktop server from another device running under the same network.
4. Lastly add internet permission in your Android app.